# Sabre OTA_HotelResRQ INVLD CREDIT CARD TYPE NOT ACCEPTED BY PROP

Tags: sabre

Receiving "INVLD CREDIT CARD TYPE NOT ACCEPTED BY PROP" error, but Master Card appears as a valid option when I call HotelRateDescriptionLLSRQ. I'm passing in CA as the card, though Guarantees Accepted specifies multiple character codes for Master Card (including CA). How do I resolve this?

```
   <Guarantee>
       <GuaranteesAccepted>
          <PaymentCard Code="AX" Type="AMERICAN EXPRESS" />
          <PaymentCard Code="CA" Type="MASTERCARD" />
          <PaymentCard Code="DC" Type="DINERS CLUB CARD" />
          <PaymentCard Code="DS" Type="DISCOVER CARD" />
          <PaymentCard Code="IK" Type="MASTER CARD" />
          <PaymentCard Code="JC" Type="JCB CREDIT CARD" />
          <PaymentCard Code="MC" Type="MASTER CARD" />
          <PaymentCard Code="NA" Type="NONE ACCEPTED" />
          <PaymentCard Code="VI" Type="VISA" />
          <PaymentCard Code="VS" Type="VISA" />
          <Text>/GAGT             GUARANTEE TO AGENCY TIDS/IATA NUMBER</Text>
       </GuaranteesAccepted>
    </Guarantee>
```

**Calling OTA_HotelResRQ with the following:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <MessageHeader xmlns="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader">
         <From>
            <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">REMOVED</PartyId>
         </From>
         <To>
            <PartyId type="urn:x12.org:IO5:01">Sabre webservices.havail.sabre.com</PartyId>
         </To>
         <CPAId>REMOVED</CPAId>
         <ConversationId>1519099174</ConversationId>
         <Service type="sabreXML">OTA_HotelResLLSRQ</Service>
         <Action>OTA_HotelResLLSRQ</Action>
         <MessageData>
            <MessageId>1519099174</MessageId>
            <Timestamp>2018-02-19T20:59:34</Timestamp>
            <TimeToLive>2018-02-19T21:59:34</TimeToLive>
         </MessageData>
      </MessageHeader>
      <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
         <wsse:BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="wsse:Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESH!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!-3176496554278439282!433327!0</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <OTA_HotelResRQ xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ReturnHostCommand="true" TimeStamp="2015-05-12T02:00:26-06:00" Version="2.1.0">
         <Hotel>
            <BasicPropertyInfo InsertAfter="0" RPH="008" />
            <Guarantee Type="GC">
               <CC_Info>
                  <PaymentCard Code="CA" ExpireDate="2018-09" Number="****REMOVED" />
                  <PersonName>
                     <Surname>REMOVED</Surname>
                  </PersonName>
               </CC_Info>
            </Guarantee>
            <RoomType NumberOfUnits="1" />
         </Hotel>
      </OTA_HotelResRQ>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

**Full error response:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <Header>
      <eb:MessageHeader xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" eb:version="1.0" mustUnderstand="1">
         <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">Sabre webservices.havail.sabre.com</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:From>
         <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId eb:type="URI">REMOVED</eb:PartyId>
         </eb:To>
         <eb:CPAId>REMOVED</eb:CPAId>
         <eb:ConversationId>1519099174</eb:ConversationId>
         <eb:Service>OTA_HotelResLLSRQ</eb:Service>
         <eb:Action>OTA_HotelResLLSRS</eb:Action>
         <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>1364889143752860193</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2018-02-20T03:59:35</eb:Timestamp>
            <eb:RefToMessageId>1519099174</eb:RefToMessageId>
         </eb:MessageData>
      </eb:MessageHeader>
      <Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext">
         <BinarySecurityToken valueType="String" EncodingType="Base64Binary">Shared/IDL:IceSess\/SessMgr:1\.0.IDL/Common/!ICESMS\/RESH!ICESMSLB\/RES.LB!-3176496554278439282!433327!0</BinarySecurityToken>
      </Security>
   </Header>
   <Body>
      <OTA_HotelResRS xmlns="http://webservices.sabre.com/sabreXML/2011/10" xmlns:stl="http://services.sabre.com/STL/v01" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="2.1.0">
         <ApplicationResults status="NotProcessed">
            <Error type="BusinessLogic" timeStamp="2018-02-19T21:59:35-06:00">
               <SystemSpecificResults>
                  <HostCommand LNIATA="222222">/0/0H1½Ú008/GCCA****REMOVEDEXP 09 18-REMOVED</HostCommand>
                  <Message code="0">½øINVLD½ø CREDIT CARD TYPE NOT ACCEPTED BY PROP</Message>
                  <ShortText>ERR.SWS.HOST.ERROR_IN_RESPONSE</ShortText>
               </SystemSpecificResults>
            </Error>
         </ApplicationResults>
      </OTA_HotelResRS>
   </Body>
</Envelope>
```

**Edit** Use G instead of GC for guarantee types of G. G = Guarantee with Card while GC = Guarantee to Company. Easy to understand why I thought GC meant the latter. Why do we need these? Because Sabre was built in the 50s and it hates you. It would also be nice if Sabre reported errors correctly as this was a problem with the Guarantee Type and not with the type of credit card. My hate for sabre is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to contact Sabre's Web Services Support team. The property could be sending incorrect information and they should be able to reach the hotel or its GDS.

Comment: The response specifies GAGT as the guarantee type code, but our system just uses GC when GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="G" for the rate plan. Do you think this has anything to do with it? Sabre is insanity.

Comment: If you got GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="G" in the HOD response, then you should use Guarantee Type="G" in the HotelRes request. This is likely related to the error that you have.

Comment: Yes I just realized that and released a patch.  My question now includes that answer. I unfortunately believed GC = Guarantee with Card as we were refactoring some code. Would be nice if Sabre reported accurate errors though.